# Custom maven archetype how to declare groupId?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I am developing custom maven archetype and I was able to create it successfully. The problem is I used `${groupId}` instead of `${project.groupId}`. If groupId is declared as `${project.groupId}`.I am getting this error when generating sample project.

```
[ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${project.groupId}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'project.groupId': [groupId] -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'groupId' with value '${project.groupId}' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 25, column 14
```

But when grouId is declared as `${groupId}` I am getting this warning when building sample project which was generated from maven archetype.

```
[WARNING] The expression ${groupId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.groupId} insteadS
```

**Is there any workaround for this?**

Comment: where are you using the `${groupId}` placeholder in the generated project?

Comment: could you provide the pom.xml which is inside the folder archetype-resources of your archetype project ?

Comment: Here is the custom maven archetype https://github.com/GPrathap/cdmf-devicetype-archetype